# How to display javascript variable in a dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a search form that can display a list of persons matching the searching filters.
Once the search results are displayed, I want a link (id=names_list) that, when clicked, displays a dialog box displaying the list of the persons names.

I don't understand why this code is not working :

```
 <a id="names_list" href="#">Names list</a>

    {% for person in persons %}
       <a class="name_for_mylist">{{ person | name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}

    <script>        
            $(document).ready(function()    
            {
                $("#names_list").click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var list = "";
                    $(".name_for_mylist").each(function(){
                        list += $(this).html() + "; ";
                    });
                    var box=list.dialog({ title: "Names list" });
                    box.show();
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The jQuery UI `.dialog()` function has to be applied to an HTML element in the DOM, not a string.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so how to pass this list variable into my dialog content?

Comment: See the answer from xdazz for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is a string, and it doesn't have the method `.dialog`.

You should do like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#names_list").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var list = "";
        $(".name_for_mylist").each(function () {
            list += $(this).html() + "; ";
        });
        $('<div>').html(list).appendTo('body').dialog({
            title: "Names list"
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var liste = "";
$(".name_for_mylist").each(function(){
  list += $(this).html() + "; ";
});
```

u declared liste variable and you are adding $(this).html() to list variable.

try changing `list+= $(this).html()+ ';';` to  `liste+= $(this).html()+ ';';`

Comment: The typo was fixed very shortly after the question was posted.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var box=list.dialog({ title: "Names list" });
```

to this

```
var box=$(list).dialog({ title: "Names list" });
```

You can put damn near anything in the jquery wrapper.

<strike>About half way through your javascript,</strike>

```
var liste = "";
```

Extra "e" at the end of "list"

Comment: Yes sorry but it was just absent-mindedness on my part when writing the code on stack overflow :(